# How to get a Mouse Cursor Type?

Tags: ruby, cursor, selenium-webdriver

I am currently testing a web application and facing a problem. I need to know what type of cursor now to open the context menu. It's impossible to find an element that can be context (right mouse button) clicked on, I can only track the cursor type.

For example. if you move your cursor over a link it turns into a hand; or when you move your cursor over textfield it turns into "I". I need to know when the cursor has changed.

Do you have any ideas, how can I do this?

Comment: need more informations...not sure what you are looking for,,

Comment: For example, if you could give us the web page you're trying to test, that would be helpful.

Comment: For example. if you move your cursor over a link it turns into a hand. I need to know when the cursor has changed.

Comment: Or when you move your cursor over textfield it turns into "I"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Selenium can only query things in your browser, and the cursor display is controlled by your OS.

The best I can suggest would be to check the CSS cursor attribute value using:

```
function String getElementCursorType(WebElement element) {
    return element.getCssValue("cursor");
}
```

See http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_cursor for a list of possible return values and a live demo to see the actual cursor used by your system.